# $_POST param was modified/truncated

Tags: php, apache, post, encryption

When I send data in POST to a php script this post data was truncated/modified ...

I have a variable $encrypted sent with Guzzle or Curl to an endpoint which return post data in json (for example)

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

$encrypted before sending:

```
string(88) "D4PYDZou2pEugJKyR0vpjpdKplQ0g/pxNOrqomImFgdtKjuKA3WAQuFAt3OUlghBnGpMz2dOnYGOkGUyz5Vd7g=="
```

$encrypted received from endpoint

```
string(71) "D PYDZou2pEugJKyR0vpjpdKplQ0g/pxNOrqomImFgdtKjuKA3WAQuFAt3OUlghBnGpMz2d"
```

when I check RAW data with file_get_contents("php://input");

$encrypted is OK but not in $_POST ...

My script is running by apache/php through nginx

Thx.

Remi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to post base64 data.

```
function base64_urlencode($data)
{
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}

function base64_urldecode($data)
{
    return base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));
}
```

this methods avoid special chars in string.