# PHP HMAC_HASH SHA256 returns incorrect value

Tags: php, jwt

I'm trying to generate JWT using HMAC256 in PHP. But I noticed that the response returns invalid / incorrect value. I compared the value in JWT website https://jwt.io/#debugger-io that why I say it's incorrect.

```
$token = '*******-****-****-****-*********';
    
 $header = array(
    "alg" => "HS256",
    "typ" => "JWT"
);
    
$header = json_encode($header);
$header = base64_encode($header);

$payload = array(
   "id" => "XXXX"
);

 $payload = json_encode($payload);
 $payload = base64_encode($payload);
 $payload = str_replace('==', '', $payload);

 $toHash = $header .'.'. $payload;

 $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $toHash, $token, true);
 $signature = base64_encode($signature);

 // yzt9U/pSc+PFnXHqKIvMDEkMhlUnVL6RuNtqciAPsXw= (Token generated in PHP)
 // yzt9U_pSc-PFnXHqKIvMDEkMhlUnVL6RuNtqciAPsXw (Token generated in JWT website)
```

Token should be the same as generated in JWT.

Comment: just a matter of encoding, as answered in the linked q/a

Comment: you might still want to read the linked answer and understand the different encoding. Base64 vs. Base64url has nothing to do with php or python, it's language independent.

Comment: got it now. I'll try sir

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384015/post-param-was-modified-truncated) for an elegant wrapper.

Comment: already done sir and answer my questions. thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I post my answer here for everyone.

```
public function base64url_encode($data) {

$data = str_replace(array('+', '/'), array('-', '_'), base64_encode($data));
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: What about the `=` at the end of the token?